# Pourquoi « distinguable » avec un « u » ?

Tags: étymologie, orthographe, adjectifs, suffixes

En orthographe, il y a une règle qui stipule que tous les verbes se terminant par *-guer* prennent la forme *-gable* pour l'adjectif associé.

Exemples :

- « naviguer » → « navigable »
- « conjuguer » → « conjugable »

Cependant, cette règle s'applique à tous les verbes sauf l'adjectif « distinguable » (terminaison en *-guable*) qui dérive du verbe « distinguer ».

Savez-vous pourquoi cet adjectif se **distingue** des autres ?

Comment: "Distinguable" n'est pas dans le TLF ni dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie. Pourtant, étrangement, il est dans le Larousse. http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/distinguable/26066

Comment: Pour les amateurs de ngrams: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=distingable%2C+distinguable&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: Bien que le mot ne soit pas dans tous les dicitonnaires, il existe bien. Le ngram le prouve d'ailleurs.

Comment: @Zistoloen Oui, clairement. Mon commentaire exprime une surprise, en fait.

Comment: @Shlubu - *Dictionnaire :* DISTINGUABLE : adj - XVII°, repris 1877 ; de distinguer | Que l'on peut distinguer (3° ou 4°) ... ;signé : le petit Robert. J'avoue ignorer la signification de (3° ou 4°) ; *Historique :* Toute précieuse que soit Mlle de La Trousse, elle a de l'esprit, par là je suis assurée qu'elle vous distingue, comme elle le doit, du reste de messieurs de Caen, que je ne crois pas tous aussi distinguables que vous l'êtes, Mme DE LA FAYETTE, Lettre à Huet, 14 nov. 1662, dans le Correspondant, 25 déc. 1876, p. 1095 (Le Littré) ; *Explication du U ?* NEANT

Answer (score 8):

*Naviguer*, *fatiguer*, etc. viennent respectivement du latin *navigo (-are*, *-avi*, -*atum*), *fatigo* (-*are*, -*avi*, -*atum*), etc. : tous des infinitifs en `-gare`. L'adjectif correspondant provident du suffixe -*bilis* ajouté à la racine contenant un `a` (*[navigabilis](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/navigabilis#la)* est attesté, *fatigabilis* aussi [au moins en latin tardif](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fatigable)). Ce suffixe s'est contracté en français moderne en `-a-` + `-ble`.

En français, on a ajouté un `u` lorsque cela était nécessaire pour prononcer le G dur. Le `u` est donc nécessaire dans le verbe à l'infinitif (et à beaucoup d'autres formes) ; on l'a étendu à toutes les formes du verbe. En revanche l'adjectif en -gable n'a pas eu besoin d'un `u` supplémentaire.

*Distinguer* vient du latin *[distinguo](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/distinguo#la)* (-*ere*, *distinxi*, *distinctum*). Le `u` était déjà présent en latin, et n'a jamais disparu en français même si la prononciation le rendait superflu. Je ne trouve qu'un autre mot (hors imports) qui ait conservé `-gua-` : *[baguage](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baguage)* (de bague au sens d'anneau — aucun rapport avec le *bagage* qui vient de l'ancien français *bagues* signifiant *paquet* (qui lui est peut-être apparenté)).

Pour d'autres adjectifs rares qui semblent dérivés directement du verbe et non d'un adjectif latin, l'orthographe -gable prédomine, mais on trouve aussi une minorité de -guable: *[conjugable](https://www.google.com/search?q=%conjugable%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_fr)* mais aussi quelques *[conjuguable](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22conjuguable%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_fr)* (de *conjugare*), *[homologable](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22homologable%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_fr)* mais aussi quelques *[homologuable](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22homologuable%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_fr)* (de *homologare*), *[divulgable](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22divulgable%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_fr)* mais aussi quelques *[divulguable](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22divulguable%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_fr)* (de *divulgare*), etc. Je pense que c'est la proximité du verbe et qui incite à garder le `u`, même si les orthographes en `u` sont suffisamment minoritaires pour qu'on puisse les considérer comme incorrectes.

Comment: +1 : Merci Gilles pour cette bonne tentative de réponse.

Comment: @Zistoloen De rien, surtout que j'avais loupé quelque chose d'important : *distinguer* vient de *distingUo*. On n'a donc pas ajouté de U au verbe, on a omis de le retirer de l'adjectif !

Answer (score 6):

Comme l'a souligné Shlublu, **distinguable** n'est pas présent dans tous les dictionnaires. L'information reste donc à prendre avec des pincettes.

Sur [ce site](http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/%C2%AB-infatigable-%C2%BB-ou-%C2%AB-infatiguable-%C2%BB), Bruno Dewaele, champion du monde d'orthographe, explique que le *u* de **distinguable** pourrait venir de l'utilisation du mot **distinguo** dans la langue française.

> On se répand en conjectures sur le cas très particulier de l’adjectif
>   « distinguable » : pourquoi ce « u » a-t-il survécu ici alors qu’il a
>   disparu partout ailleurs ? Dès le XIXe siècle pourtant, il avait été
>   proposé de l’aligner sur les finales en « -gable ». Le mot d’origine
>   latine distinguo, qui s’est maintenu dans notre langue pour désigner
>   une distinction subtile, y est-il pour quelque chose ? Allez savoir…

Pour ce qui est de la définition de [distinguo](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/distinguo) :

> Action d'énoncer une distinction dans une argumentation.

Au final, il n'y a donc rien de certain sur la provenance de ce mot. Ce qui est sûr est que **distinguable** est le seul mot en *-gable* qui s'écrit avec un *u*.

Comment: Cela ne donne pas la réponse à ma question puisque ce sont des suppositions mais merci quand même.

Answer (score -4):

Le mot est un **barbarisme**, peu importe son orthographe donc.

De la même racine ont été formés :

- distinct = que l'on peut distinguer
- distinctif = qui sert à distinguer

qui sont nécessaires et suffisants ... et sonnent mieux.

Comment: C'est un barbarisme, comme la quasi-totalité des mots français, puisque ce n'est pas un mot grec. Et alors? *Distinct* n'est pas exactement synonyme de *distinguable* : *distinct* signifie qu'il y a une différence, alors que *distinguable* apporte la nuance que la différence est perceptible. Le mot n'est donc pas redondant ni superflu (ce qui au demeurant n'est pas un défaut ni un inconvénient). Quand à sonner mieux, c'est un pur jugement de valeur.

Comment: Je comprends très mal cette critique. Pour m'en remettre à une source moins ancienne que l'Antiquité Grecque, à savoir le Littré, le sens de barbarisme n'a plus rien à voir avec le manque d'atticisme. Le même auteur définit "distinct" comme 1) Que l'on distingue 2) Qui se discerne 3) Clair, précis - il ne daigne pas mentionner "distinguable"

Comment: Un barbarisme serait alors un mot qui n'est pas dans le Littré ? C'est curieux, comme définition — et cela ferait de ce sens un barbarisme puisque ce n'est pas comme cela que Littré définit le mot. Littré omet bien des mots utilisé par Flaubert ou Hugo ; je ne considère pas ces écrivains comme des barbares, aussi ne considéré-je pas les mots qu'ils emploient comme des barbarismes.